# "no module named 'dotenv'" in when trying to set up autogpt

Tags: python-dotenv, autogpt

When im trying to set up auto gpt like this:

```
PS C:\Users\******\Downloads\Auto-GPT-master> python3 c:\Users\******\Downloads\Auto-GPT-master\Auto-GPT-master\main.py
```

This error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\******\Downloads\Auto-GPT-master\Auto-GPT-master\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from autogpt import main
  File "c:\Users\******\Downloads\Auto-GPT-master\Auto-GPT-master\autogpt\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>       
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Is this related to Visual Studio Code? Does it work normally in any other terminal?

Comment: i dont know. i didnt try it on other terminals

Comment: I don't mean anything fancy when I mention other terminals. Just open a PowerShell window from the Start menu and run the same exact command. It looks unusual that your text editor is to blame for an external process it doesn't interact with.

Comment: I tried it in powershell and it didnt work, the same error appears